# Codificacion de caracteres del doc HTML no fue declarada

Tags: javascript, html

estoy practicando formularios y su validacion con js y tengo el siguiente problema:

> La codificación de caracteres del documento HTML no fue declarada. El documento se mostrará con texto "basura" en algunas configuraciones de navegador si el documento contiene caracteres duera del rango US-ASCII. La codificación de caracteres de la página debe ser declarada en el documento o en el protocolo de transferencia.

Me lleva directamente a una pagina de prueba, para ver si pasaba o no la validacion hecha en js

El codigo de HTML es este:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contacto</h1>
    <main>
        <form action="test.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar.js();">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Información Personal</legend>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">

            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" class="boton submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>

    </main>

    <script src="js/validar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Y el de la validacion en javascript es este: 

    function validar(){
    var nombre;
    nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;

    if(nombre === ''){
        alert("El campo nombre es necesario");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te sale ese mensaje?

Comment: Al abrir la consola en la pagina de prueba me sale eso, se salta la validacion de si el campo está vacio

Comment: Me refiero al mensaje "La codificación de caracteres del documento HTML no fue declarada". No consigo reproducir tu problema, exceptuando el hecho de que `onsubmit="return validar.js();"` no es válido. El nombre de la función es `validar` a secas, no debes poner el nombre del archivo, sólo el nombre de la función: `onsubmit="return validar();"`.

Comment: Tienes razon, muchas gracias, pase por alto eso y me fije en otras cosas, muchas gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Si trato de reproducir tu problema el único mensaje de error que me sale es:

> Uncaught TypeError: `validar.js` is not a function at `HTMLFormElement.onsubmit` (`js:21`)

Código:

```js
function validar(){
    var nombre;
    nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;

    if(nombre === ''){
        alert("El campo nombre es necesario");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contacto</h1>
    <main>
        <form action="test.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar.js();">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Información Personal</legend>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">

            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" class="boton submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>

    </main>

    <script src="js/validar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ese mensaje está provocado por una llamada a una función desconocida en la siguiente línea:

```
<form action="test.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar.js();">
```

Tratas de llamar a la función `validar.js()` (que no está definida tal y como dice el error) cuando lo que deseas es llamar a la función que has creado que se llama `validar()`, por lo que la solución sería cambiar el nombre al correcto:

```
<form action="test.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar();">
```

Quedando:

```js
function validar(){
    var nombre;
    nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;

    if(nombre === ''){
        alert("El campo nombre es necesario");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contacto</h1>
    <main>
        <form action="test.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar();">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Información Personal</legend>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">

            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" class="boton submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>

    </main>

    <script src="js/validar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza tu navegador a una versión mas nueva.

O bueno, siempre si estas usando internet explorer puedes intentar esto:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Si usas alguna versión vieja de interent explorer.