# ClosedXML Error al exportar Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo un método para exportar información a un excel para que se pueda descargar

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<FileResult> ExportToExcel(Schedule schedule)
    {           
        try
        {
            List<Service> services = await _servicesService.GetServicesByDate(UserInfo.CompanyId, schedule.Date, UserInfo.Token);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Services");
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
            {
                new DataColumn("Orden", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Fecha"),
                new DataColumn("Hora"),
                new DataColumn("Origen"),
                new DataColumn("Destino"),
                new DataColumn("Pasajeros", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Cliente"),
                new DataColumn("Estatus"),
                new DataColumn("Tipo"),
                new DataColumn("Moneda"),
                new DataColumn("Total", typeof(decimal)),
                new DataColumn("Tipo Pago"),
                new DataColumn("Vendedor"),
                new DataColumn("Vehículo"),
                new DataColumn("Operador"),
                new DataColumn("Notas")
            });
            for (int i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
            {
                Service service = services[i];
                dt.Rows.Add(
                    service.Id,
                    service.ServiceDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    service.ServiceDetail.Hour.ToString(),
                    service.ServiceDetail.DepartureServiceName,
                    service.ServiceDetail.ArrivalServiceName,
                    service.ServiceDetail.Pax,
                    service.TravelerName,
                    service.ServiceStatusId == 5 ? _sharedLocalizer["Cancelled"] : _sharedLocalizer["Pending"] ,
                    service.ServiceDetail.ShuttleType == 1 ? "Sencillo" : "Redondo",
                    service.ServiceDetail.CurrencyId == 1 ? "MXN" : "USD",
                    service.ServiceDetail.Amount.ToString("#,#.00"),
                    service.ServiceDetail.PaymentType == 1 ? "Tarjeta de crédito" : service.ServiceDetail.PaymentType == 2 ? "Tarjeta de debito" : "Efectivo",
                    service.UserName,
                    service.VehicleNumberPlate,
                    service.DriverName,
                    service.Notes
                    );
            }
            string handle = UserInfo.Surname + "ServicesReport";
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    
                    wb.SaveAs(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    TempData[handle] = ms.ToArray();
                    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Services Report " + schedule.Date.Year.ToString() + "-" + schedule.Date.Month.ToString() + "-" + schedule.Date.Day.ToString() + ".xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception emma)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar y usar el método, no se descarga el archivo y me devuelve un error 500 internal server

y en consola me devuelve el siguiente mensaje

> La codificación de caracteres del documento de texto sin formato no fue declarada. El documento se mostrará con texto "basura" en algunas configuraciones de navegador si el documento contiene caracteres externos al rango US-ASCII. La codificación de caracteres de la página debe ser declarada en el protocolo de transferencia o el archivo necesita usar una marca de orden de byte como firma de codificación.

Aún no he detectado que es lo que lo ocasiona, he leido que es porque no estoy declarando la codificación y en otros casos porque algún campo es muy largo....

Comment: primero lo primero, imprime lo que hay en la lista de "services", mira rápidamente si hay algún caracter extraño, a veces el cambio de UTF a otro encoding o viceversa genera texto "basura", es decir, texto ilegible (salen puros cuadraditos)

Comment: Lo unico  de catracteres "extraños" que veo son los acentos, no veo otro caracter raro

Comment: Coloca breakpoints para confirmar que ese es el problema, prueba esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25321848/3613462

Comment: No me funcionó, ninguna de las opciones

Comment: Aquí hay otra situación similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/347778/822

Comment: Si pero yo hago todo desde el controller, no uso JS

Comment: ¿Has visto a detalle la pregunta? ¿Has visto el HTML? Ahi hay algo que tienen en común, por otro lado, antes que salten las alarmas por tener comentarios extensos, avisa si vas a la sala de chat para colaborar con tu caso :D

Comment: Creo que sería bueno que dieras un ejemplo de los datos que contiene tu dataset, de tal manera que se pueda reproducir tu error con la información que das en tu publicación.

Comment: Resolví el problema yo mismo, he dado mi respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que ocasiona que no se generara el Excel y me diera un error HTTP 500 era debido a que en los parametros de return file, debería ir de esta forma

```
return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/ms-excel", "Services Report " + schedule.Date.Year.ToString() + "-" + schedule.Date.Month.ToString() + "-" + schedule.Date.Day.ToString() + ".xlsx");
```

Agregando este parametro de return file me funciono:

> "application/ms-excel"